# How to progressively count the number of characters in a String Array? -Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, cycle

I'm a 1st College student with no prior coding experience. I'm working on a text editor for my second assignment. One of the many features of this text editor is the ability to count the number of characters in a string, and, since this is a string array, there are multiple of them. Here's what I've got thus far:

```
int maxSize=100;
int [] nChars = new int[maxSize];
String [] linhas = new String[maxSize];

    for (int i=0; i<maxSize;i++){
        nChars[i]=lines[i].charAt(i);
        System.out.println(lines[i]+ " - " + nChars[i]); \\print the line and the respective number of characters
```

Any help is apreciated, I'm pretty much stuck.

Comment: The number of characters in a String is just the `.length()` of the string.  Ask your professor though if you're allowed to use that method.

Comment: @markspace please correct .lenght -> length

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks really obvious in hindsight. :)

Comment: Even if you're allowed to use length().  I think it would be a good exercise to write your own version.  Take a string as a parameter and return its length.  Then call your newly built function in the loop you posted.

Comment: @markspace: You should post your comment as an answer instead of as a comment. The OP should accept your answer after you post it. It's clearly the correct one.

Comment: @ray I dunno, this seems close to a syntax question to me.  Not the greatest use of StackOverflow.

Comment: @markspace: Not sure about that. Pointing out to OP that he should use `.length()` method of a string is not related to language *syntax* (i.e. grammar rules). But it seems you missed your chance. I avoided posting my answer b/c I thought you should've had the accepted response for posting here first ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you are searching for is simply the .legth() function which will return the numbers of characters in a String.

```
String myString = "testString";
System.out.println("The string has " + myString.length() + " characters");

// output: The string has 10 characters
```

If you have an array of strings then just iterate through it and use the length() function on each element.

Greetings Raven